# If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ is closed, then show that $A$ is the union of a perfect set (which may be empty) and a countable set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is a special case of Baby Rudin's Exercise 2.28 [Is every set in a separable metric space the union of a perfect set and a set that is at most countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469200/is-every-set-in-a-separable-metric-space-the-union-of-a-perfect-set-and-a-set-th)  .

Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is special, I was trying to prove it without using the concepts of countable dense subsets and condensations points. I got the following proof and I was wondering if anyone knows the proof is correct.

Since $A$ is closed, we have $A=$cl$(A)=I(A)\cup A'$ where $I(A)$ is the set of isolated points of $A$ and $A'$ is the set of accumulation (limit) points of $A$.

Claim: $I(A)$ is countable. Let $a\in I(A)$. Then there exists an open set $V(a)$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $a\in V(a)$ and $V(a)\cap A=\{a\}$. So for all $a,b\in I(A)$, if $a\neq b$, then $V(a)\cap V(b)=\emptyset$. Since $\mathbb{Q}^k$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^k$, for all $a\in I(A)$, there exists $a'\in V(a)$ such that $a'\in\mathbb{Q}^k$. Now define $\varepsilon:I(A)\mapsto\mathbb{Q}^k$ such that $a\mapsto a'$. Then $\varepsilon$ is an injection. Since $\mathbb{Q}^k$ is countable, $I(A)$ is countable as well.

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A^{(n+1)}$ be the set of accumulation points of $A^{(n)}$ where $A^{(0)}=A$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $A^{(n)}$ is closed, $A^{(n)}=I(A^{(n)})\cup A^{(n+1)}$. So $A=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I(A^{(n)})\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}\right)$. By Claim 2, $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I(A^{(n)})$ is countable. Since $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}$ is the intersection of closed sets, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}$ is closed.

Claim: $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}$ has no isolated points. Suppose $x$ is an isolated points of $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}$. Then $x\in A^{(N)}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. But then $x\notin A^{(N+1)}$ which is a contradiction.

Hence $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^{(n)}$ is perfect.

Comment: You’ll have to work a little harder to show that $I(A)$ is countable. You don’t know that $V(a)\cap V(b)=\varnothing$: you know only that $V(a)\cap V(b)\cap A=\varnothing$. For instance, if $A=\{0,3\}$, $V(0)$ might be $(-1,2)$, and $V(3)$ might be $(1,4)$. That can be fixed without *too* much trouble, but your final claim is a bigger problem: it’s not necessarily true. There are closed subsets $A$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A^{(n)}$ does have isolated points.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi Prof. Scott, thanks for your comment. Do you know a counterexample for my last claim?

Comment: Yes. The ordinal space $\omega^\omega+1$, where the exponentiation is ordinal exponentiation, can be embedded as a closed subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$, and for that $A$ the set $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A^{(n)}$ is a singleton, a one-point set. The ordinal space $\omega^{\omega+1}+1$ can also be embedded as a closed set, and in that case $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A^{(n)}$ turns out to be homeomorphic to the subset $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You’re very welcome!